# Java annotation that expands/resolves to many annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a set of Java annotation that I quite frequently use, like this:

```
@SomeAnnotation(Something)
@SomeOtherAnnotation
@SomeLastAnnotation(SomethingElse)
class Foo
{
    /* ... */
}
```

As I use all these annotations together quite often, and I may have to add to them in everywhere they are used once in a while, I would like to create a new annotation that I can use instead. This annotation should then "resolve" to all the annotations that I define somewhere.

```
@MySuperAnnotation
class Foo
{
    /* ... */
}
```

**How do I declare `@MySuperAnnotation` such that it "resolves" to all the other annotations?**

Comment: You could write your own annotation and a corresponding annotation processor, which would create a class with the above annotations tagged on.

Comment: @Oliver Weiler: Do you mean a separate tool, that will preprocess the source and add the annotations I want?

Comment: @bjarkref Yes, you would have to write this on your own, i.e. you'd have to write a custom annotationprocessor, which processes your annotations via reflections and writes another class with the annotations and code you want.

Comment: http://javadude.com/articles/annotations/index.html. See part 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, not without rewriting all of the tools and reflection code that looks for the original annotations.

(Or, as Oliver suggests, you could postprocess the compiled .class files to replace the annotations with something different -- not that I know of any tools that will do that for you automatically).

Comment: I think it's possible but not in the way the OP hoped for. (I did not downvote you).

Comment: Damn, I am just trying to avoid repeating myself all-over the code. (DRY you know. :) )

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no way. But if you are using spring ( >= 3.0 ) it is possible with custom annotations. Simple example [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/avoid-spring-annotation-code-smell-use-spring3-custom-annotations).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with AspectJ with the declare annotation instruction: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-declare.html

in your context, this should work:

```
public aspect Declaration {
    declare @type: @MySuperAnnotation *: @SomeAnnotation(Something);
    declare @type: @MySuperAnnotation *: @SomeOtherAnnotation;
    declare @type: @MySuperAnnotation *: @SomeLastAnnotation(SomethingElse);
}
```